# NextJS afterInteractive still blocking load according to PageSpeedInsights

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager

I have a nextjs app where in the _app.js file I am importing Google Tag Manager as per the nextjs documentation:

```
      <Script
       id="googleAnalytics0"
       src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXX"
       strategy="lazyOnload"
      />
      <Script
       id="googleAnalytics"
       strategy="lazyOnload"
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
         __html: `
           window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
           function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
           gtag('js', new Date());

           gtag('config', 'XXX');
         `
       }}
      ></Script>
```

When I do a lighthouse test built into chrome there are no issues - however when I do a [Page speed insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev) test it says that google tag manager is blocking the load.

[image: page speed insights test]

I have tried changing strategy="lazyOnload" to strategy="afterInteractive" and this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager (and Google Analytics) will always run on the main thread, so it will always incur "Main Thread Blocking Time" in Google Page Speed.

The `strategy` property of the Next.js `Script` tag only changes the timing when these scripts are loaded. For a detailed overview, you can use the [Performance tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/) in the Developer tools of your browser.

I wrote a blogpost about how to implement GTM and GA in Next.js [here](https://www.rodyvansambeek.com/blog/easiest-ga4-integration-nextjs-13-gtm-guide)

If you have multiple tags set-up in your GTM container, you should keep an eye on the performance of your website, multiple tags can quickly eat up a lot of your Core Web Vitals performance. You could use GTM Server-Side tracking to solve this.

For more info, see these links:

- [Page speed Tag Manager's best practices](https://web.dev/tag-best-practices/)
- [Improving page speed with server-side google tag manager](https://connective3.com/blog/improving-page-speed-with-server-side-google-tag-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

Add Async to your tag. That helps it load without blocking as bad. In testing Lazyload for me provided worse lighthouse scores.

```
  {analytics_tag &&
    <>
      <Script
        async
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${analytics_tag}`}
        id="Google-Analytics-Src"
      />
      <Script
        id="Google-Analytics-Data-Layer"
        async
      >
        {`
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${analytics_tag}');
          `}
      </Script>
    </>
  }
```